# Does Freenas require each plugin to be under a jail?

Tags: freenas, chroot-jail

I know that Jails are like VMs running under `Freenas`. And I have `Plex` and `Transmission` installed using the Plugin feature on `Freenas`. Question is: Can I have it that both of these apps installed in the same jail? Why does `Freenas` install them in different jails?